# Gravity fan does not work when powered by 3.3V ESP8266

Tags: esp8266

The gravity fan has 3 pins. I connected one pin to the ground, one pin to the digital pin numbered 2 on ESP8266. I uploaded this code but the fan doesn't run at all. The fan supposedly uses a 5V power supply but the ESP8266 only supplies 3.3V. Could this be the problem?

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
}
```

Comment: If the fan needs 5V power you need to give it 5V power. 3.3V logic is not 5V power.

Comment: Don't power stuff from I/O pins. An LED may work, but a fan will require too much power and also has a possibility to generate power (when turned by hand/wind) and may damage the pin.

Answer (score 1):

The ESP can only supply 12 milliamperes of current. The fan most likely uses a whole lot more. You could for example uses a transistor to turn on the fan.